# No internet connection - - how to reinstall network drivers on Bionic?

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04

I did something bad to my internet drivers (trying to install/make Bluetooth work) and now have no connection.

Have tried v arious published fixes but so far no positive results.
Any help much appreciated!

Output:

```
guy@guy-Serie-1500:~$ lspci | egrep -i --color 'network|ethernet'
01:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)


guy@guy-Serie-1500:~$ ifconfig -a
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 7614  bytes 471123 (471.1 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 7614  bytes 471123 (471.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

guy@guy-Serie-1500:~$ sudo lshw -class network
[sudo] password for guy: 
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
       vendor: Ralink corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f0510000-f051ffff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f0404000-f0404fff memory:f0400000-f0403fff
```

Comment: Do you have more than one kernel version installed? Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: `uname -r` and also: `ls /boot | grep vm` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: hi - thanks - output: guy@guy-Serie-1500:~$ uname -r
4.15.0-43-generic
guy@guy-Serie-1500:~$ ls /boot | grep vm
vmlinuz-4.15.0-42-generic
vmlinuz-4.15.0-43-generic

Comment: This looks like it could be dealt with better in chat, so I created one: [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89175/discussion-on-question-by-guy-no-internet-connection-how-to-reinstall-networ).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please reboot. Using the Shift key, interrupt the boot process to get to the GRUB menu: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2

Select Advanced Options and scroll down to the earlier kernel version, 4.15.0-42-generic. Press Enter to boot it.

[image]

Once you are booted into -42, I suspect that your networking will now work. If so, we'll reinstall -43:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-image-4.15.0-43-generic
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-modules-4.15.0-43-generic
```

After all is completed, reboot and -43 should now also be working.

**EDIT**: In our chat, we found that the ethernet driver you installed was r8168-dkms. The driver either is not signed ar not signed properly to satisfy Secure Boot. After you disabled Secure Boot in the BIOS/EFI, the driver loaded correctly and the ethernet is working.

We also found that the wireless driver was blacklisted. We removed the blacklist, flipped the Airplane Mode switch and now the wireless is also working.

Comment: changed boot order with grub customizer (as system working) and rebooted, now with cable connection, reinstalled -43 and now just about to reboot into that - will let you know how it all works out.  Meanwhile, many thanks, you were such a great help after hours of dead ends.  btw, I really like chilis and grow them in my garden.  - - last word, any chance we can see about installing bluetooth...? ;-) thanks again - G :>=

Comment: ok - that didn't work.  Newly installed -43 comes up without ethernet or wifi...

Comment: Does `sudo lshw -C network` still show as unclaimed? What is the exact response to: `sudo modprobe rt2800pci`?

Comment: sudo lshw -C network still shows as unclaimed - see below for readout - after doing these two tests the "airplane mode" icon was on, but there was no way to change the hardware switch...

Comment: guy@guy-Serie-1500:~$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for guy: 
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
       vendor: Ralink corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f0510000-f051ffff

Comment: cont...  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f0404000-f0404fff memory:f0400000-f0403fff

Comment: guy@guy-Serie-1500:~$ sudo modprobe rt2800pci
guy@guy-Serie-1500:~$ sudo modprobe rt2800pci
guy@guy-Serie-1500:~$

Comment: as you see - no respnse to sudo modprobe rt2800pci

Comment: After loading the correct driver for your wireless, *rt2800pci*, did the wireless start up? `iwconfig` and also: `dmesg | grep rt2` and also: `rfkill list all`

Comment: Nothing doing...guy@guy-Serie-1500:~$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

guy@guy-Serie-1500:~$ dmesg | grep rt2
guy@guy-Serie-1500:~$ rfkill list all
guy@guy-Serie-1500:~$

Comment: Please join me in chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89101/room-for-guy-and-chili555-from-https-askubuntu-com-questions-1114230-no-interne

Comment: says I need 20 reputation to talk...

Comment: can do facebook or telegram..

Comment: Lemme see what I can do. BRB

Comment: No luck so far getting a moderators intervention. I am installing telegram

Comment: what is your telegram identity?

Comment: If it is more comfortable, email your telegram details to: wrweston at ubuntu dot com

Comment: Hey @chili555, I'm facing the same issue, but even reinstalling the Kernel with a previous version, the problem still exists. I think my wifi driver (and wired) are backlisted too, how did you make to remove it?

Comment: @Lucius Please start your own new question.

Comment: @chili555 I did it, here it is https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/636447/connection-problems-after-docker-install if you want to help, I would appreciate it :)