# Suddenly no internet - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, internet

All of a sudden, I cannot get an internet connection. System is Ubuntu 18.04 desktop PC connected via ethernet, although I've also tried connecting via Wifi to no avail. It's been working fine for over a year, so I cannot understand what has changed.

All other devices in the house work absolutely fine. In fact the PC in question is a dual-boot with Windows 10 and that connects no problem.

I've Googled a number of solutions but none seems to work.

I can ping my router but pinging 8.8.8.8 gives me "not permitted".

However, when I disable the firewall, I can briefly ping 8.8.8.8. Then after about 10 secs I get "not permitted" again. Could this have anything to do with it? Re-enabling the firewall again gives me about 10 secs of connection.

Any ideas?

Comment: what firewall is it ? on you Ubuntu box ? on the router ?

Comment: this might help https://askubuntu.com/questions/1114230/no-internet-connection-how-to-reinstall-network-drivers-on-bionic

Comment: It's the Ubuntu firewall, not the router one.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Tried booting with the previous kernel (4.15.0-96 as opposed to 4.15.0-99) and sadly still no internet.