# Network icon missing and network not connecting

Tags: networking, network-manager

i had some troubles starting with my desktop graphics, so I reinstalled gdm3 and then ubuntu-desktop again. Something went wrong on the networking on the way.

- When Ubuntu loads there is no networking icon at the top right
- Network is not connected.

I can connect manually using `ifconfig enp2s0 up` followed by `dhclient -r enp2s0` and `dhclient -r enp2s0` (as done here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025...-but-ipv4-isnt)
This is working, but I need to do it again after each reboot. How I set it to automatically connect after reboot?

I also tried setting `managed=true` in the NetworkManager.conf but it had no apparent effect.

thanks

Comment: in a terminal try nm-applet

Answer (score 0):

depends on your network Connection, if your mainboard has one of those realtek network Adapters, open a terminal end enter

lspci

for USB network adapters type

lsusb

if your Network adapter is to be seen there you only need to reinstall the driver. if its not to be seen then ist eventually broken or in sleep mode.
check in your bios if the Network adapter is running or if you dont know how to do so, look at the backside of your PC, there is a diode on the network adapter, if it is flashing slow its not working proper or the network cable is not plugged in properly.

Comment: The realtek is in the lspci output, so I tried reinstalling according to this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1114230/no-internet-connection-how-to-reinstall-network-drivers-on-bionic), but there is no effect. In there an alternative?